# Android - Camera intent not performing save, as mentioned in documentation

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I have a camera intent set up to try to create a file in the root of my device.

```
File storagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Football_Fans");
storagePath.mkdirs();
File file = new File(storagePath, "FAN_IMAGE_TEMP");                                

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);            

cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, storagePath);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,CAMERA_REQUEST_IMAGE);
```

When I run my application, I don't have any activityOnResult set, but I use fileExplorer to try to see if my file was created. My folder gets created fine, but the photo does not show up. Any idea why?

The documentation states that if an `EXTRA_OUTPUT` is set, it will write to that location. So I'm confused why it's not working.

> The caller may pass an extra EXTRA_OUTPUT to control where this image
>   will be written. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a small
>   sized image is returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field. This is
>   useful for applications that only need a small image. If the
>   EXTRA_OUTPUT is present, then the full-sized image will be written to
>   the Uri value of EXTRA_OUTPUT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use Uri. try this

```
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(storagePath));
```

Comment: Should I use `storagePath` or `file`?

Comment: Do I need to put a file extension?

Comment: I think so. you can test it by any hard code like File file = new File("/sdcard/test.jpg");

Answer (score 1):

**"..will be written to the Uri value of EXTRA_OUTPUT."**

You are passing in a File object (storagePath).  It expects a Uri so use this:

```
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(storagePath));
```

Comment: Ahh... the double-edged sword, that is documentation. On my onResultActivity I have an if statement for if data == null and it now get's caught there. Any idea why?